# How do I perform a query in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, mongoose

```
> db.users.findOne();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4db8ebb4c693ec0363000001"),
    "fb" : {
        "name" : {
            "last" : "Sss",
            "first" : "Fss",
            "full" : "Fss"
        },
        "updatedTime" : "2011-04-27T09:51:01+0000",
        "verified" : true,
        "locale" : "en_US",
        "timezone" : "-7",
        "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
        "gender" : "male",
        "alias" : "abc",

        "id" : "17447214"
    }
}
```

So that's my Mongo object. Now i want to find it via Mongoose:

```
User.findOne( { gender: "male" }, function(err, docs){
    console.log(err);  //returns Null
    console.log(docs);  //returns Null.
});
```

That doesn't work! Neither does this:

```
User.findOne( { fb: {gender:"male"} }, function...
```

Null, null.

This is my entire thing:

```
app.get('/:uid',function(req,res){
    params = {}
    User.findOne({ $where : "this.fb.gender == 'male' " }, function(err, docs){
        console.log(docs);
    });
    res.render('user', { locals:params });
});
```

Comment: Where is `User` defined?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this :

```
User.findOne( { $where : "this.fb.gender == 'male' " } )
```

or

```
User.findOne( { fb.gender : "male" } )
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why I'm getting this error when I run it? :   DEBUG: TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined
    at HTTPServer.<anonymous>

Comment: no idea, I have not used NodeJs at all, I gave the query based on my mongodb javascript experience.

Comment: It does answer the question of querying by fb.gender.  TIMEX sort of threw another question in his comment.

Answer (score 47):

I'm one of the authors of mongoose. You can do this query in one of several ways:

- `find` syntax

  ```
  User.findOne({'fb.gender': 'male'}, callback);
  ```
- `where` syntax

  ```
  User.where('fb.gender', 'male').findOne(callback);
  ```
- named scope syntax

  ```
  UserSchema.namedscope('male').where('fb.gender', 'male');
  // ...
  var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

  // Now you can write queries even more succinctly and idiomatically
  User.male.findOne(callback);
  ```

Comment: namedScope has been removed from Mongoose, but I created a plugin that mimics it: https://github.com/gberger/mongoose-named-scopes