# Verify that I am connected to my MongoDB via Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to learn Node.js and using MongoDB.
I got an insert working correctly and can insert as many objects as I want, however I cannot seem to query them at all.
I have tried using every technique posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813979/how-do-i-perform-a-query-in-mongoose) and none of them return any of my objects.
I have verified via the Mongo console that the objects exist but I just can't query them and I am absolutely lost as to why.

Here is the current code I'm using to query:

```
User.findOne({ 'user.name': 'James' }, function(user){
    console.log("Got " + user);
    res.send(user);
  });
```

Help?

**EDIT**
The above code returns "null".

Answer (score 2):

Nearly every time I post a question on SO lately I seem to find the answer myself within 15 minutes.
The answer to this one, is that my callback function is only accepting 1 argument of "user".  The first argument in the callback is any Errors that are raised, so obviously there are no errors raised.

Changing the callback to this fixes it:

```
function(err, user) {
}
```