# Mongoose find by data field from schema into services

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

If i have a **schema** like this in my mongoose

```js
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var lovSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name    : { type: String },
    values  : [{ type: String }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('lovs', lovSchema);
```

Generally in mongoose we **find document** with reff to `_id` from collections.

```js
function getOneById(id){
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    model.findOne({ _id: id })
         .exec(function (err, item) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                deferred.reject(err);
            }
            else
                console.log(item);
                deferred.resolve(item);
          });

    return deferred.promise;
} // gentOneById method ends
```

But I want to **find** the document **by Name** which is a data field in my schema.
I tried by modifying `_id` with `name` but ended with this error...

```js
{
  "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"regions\" at path \"_id\"",
  "name": "CastError",
  "type": "ObjectId",
  "value": "regions",
  "path": "_id"
}
```

Comment: Which Version of Mongoose are you using? There was a bug of some sort that I was facing too using Mongoose Version 3.8 that was causing this error. But I read on Mongoose's Github Repo that it was resolved in version 4.x

Comment: There are many different ways to query mongoose schemas, and a lot of resources available online. For example:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813979/how-do-i-perform-a-query-in-mongoose

Comment: im using "mongoose" : "3.8.1".... in services i wana search by name field not by id ... dats the requirement....

Answer (score 0):

Just use name with a String value:

```
function getOneByName(name){
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    model.findOne({ name: name})
    .exec(function (err, item) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
        else
            console.log(item);
            deferred.resolve(item);
      });

    return deferred.promise;
} // gentOneById method ends
```

You can test like this:

```
model.findOne({ name: "Bob"})
```

And see if you still get an error...

Comment: i wana test through services "http://localhost:8001/lov/:name" the content stored by name should be retrived .... im expecting like dat...